# jQuery .load() execution is not identified by .ajaxStop() handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this initialization to show "loading state" div:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading-overlay").removeClass("d-none").addClass("d-flex").show();
    console.log("AJAX request started");
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#loading-overlay").removeClass("d-flex").addClass("d-none").hide();
    console.log("AJAX request ended");
});
```

It works well when I use `$.ajax()` method, but now I need to `load()` (what should be simple Ajax `GET` request as is stated in documentation) HTML content from backend, but in this case, end of the Ajax request is not identified (content is loaded into specified `div`) but loading div does not disappear.

```
$("#js-table-trades").load("/trades/list/", function (response, status, xhr) {
            console.log("Loading is done...");
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? `load()` should still trigger `ajaxStart`/`ajaxStop` - in fact jQuery's own documentation uses `load()` in the example for ajaxStart: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/

Comment: The most current one (3.7), I will investigate the issue again.

Comment: Unable to confirm in jQuery 3.7.1: https://jsfiddle.net/jd4q37zt/ Unable to confirm in jQuery 2.2.4: https://jsfiddle.net/jd4q37zt/1/ and unable to confirm in jQuery 1.12.4: https://jsfiddle.net/jd4q37zt/2/